# Error in Installing mongoose by npm on windows 8.1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

When I try to install mongoose module on node

I have got this error

```
> kerberos@0.0.4 install C:\Users\LENOVO PC\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

C:\Users\LENOVO PC\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild -
> bson@0.2.15 install C:\Users\LENOVO PC\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

C:\Users\LENOVO PC\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson>node "C:\Program Files
\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
mongodb@1.4.18 node_modules\mongodb
├── kerberos@0.0.4
├── readable-stream@1.0.32 (string_decoder@0.10.31, inherits@2.0.1, isarray@0.0.1, core-util-is@1.0.1)
└── bson@0.2.15 (nan@1.3.0)
```

Comment: There is no error there...

Comment: node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log   this mean it's error occurred ... and I am still have error mongoose module not found

Comment: `node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log` just means it's executing the build command for that particular module (in this case `bson`) and it's redirecting stderr to a file. If there was an actual error, the output would make it pretty clear. Also, if you see the module tree like that at the end of the output, that's typically a good indicator that the module and its dependencies were installed successfully...

Comment: What command are you using to install the module? `npm install mongoose` works fine for me.